# How do I edit the text of a button when the content is displayed/actively showing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Using this example:

```js
$('[data-switch]').on('click', function(e)
  {
  var
    $page       = $('#page-2')
  , blockToShow = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-switch')
    ;

  // Hide all children.
  $page.children().hide();

  // And show the requested component.
  $page.children(blockToShow).show();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-switch="#about_me">Click to read about me</button>
<button data-switch="#education">Click to show my education</button>
<button data-switch="#about_name_bravitus">Click to read about the name Bravitus</button>

<div id="page-2">

  <div id="about_me" class="container">
    <h1>This is about me section</h1>

    <div>about me about me about me</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Hidden blocks that you show when requested. -->
  <div id="education" class="container" style="display: none;">
    <h1>This is about my education</h1>

    <div>education education education</div>
  </div>

  <div id="about_name_bravitus" class="container" style="display: none;">
    <h1>This is about the name bravitus</h1>

    <div>bravitus bravitus bravitus</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would one go about changing the font color and weight of the button text when the content is being displayed (not based on when the button is clicked)?

I have tried to find posts with a similar request, but I am greatly struggling. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do that, like this one :

```js
const
  btns_Switch  = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switch]')
, page2_parent = document.querySelector('#page-2')
  ;
btns_Switch.forEach( btn => 
  {
  btn.onclick = e =>
    {
    page2_parent.dataset.switch = btn.dataset.switch;
    setButtonActive();
    }
  })
setButtonActive();  // init on page load...

function setButtonActive()
  {
  let activBtn = page2_parent.dataset.switch;
  btns_Switch.forEach( btn => 
    btn.classList.toggle('active', activBtn === btn.dataset.switch ))
  }
```

```css
#page-2[data-switch="about_me"] > div:not(#about_me)   ,
#page-2[data-switch="education"] > div:not(#education) ,
#page-2[data-switch="about_name_bravitus"] > div:not(#about_name_bravitus)
  { 
  display : none;
  }
button.active
  {
  background  : yellow;
  font-weight : bold;
  }
```

```html
<button data-switch="about_me">Click to read about me</button>
<button data-switch="education">Click to show my education</button>
<button data-switch="about_name_bravitus">Click to read about the name Bravitus</button>

<div id="page-2" data-switch="education" >  <!-- set initial ID value -->

  <div id="about_me" class="container">
    <h1>This is about me section</h1>
    <div>about me about me about me</div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="education" class="container" >
    <h1>This is about my education</h1>
    <div>education education education</div>
  </div>

  <div id="about_name_bravitus" class="container" >
    <h1>This is about the name bravitus</h1>
    <div>bravitus bravitus bravitus</div>
  </div>
</div>
```